# Unity [MenuItem] disappears when `priority` is 100

Tags: unity

Create these classes:

```
public class MyTestComponent : MonoBehaviour
{
}
```

-

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(MyTestComponent))]
public class MyTestComponentEditor : Editor
{
    [MenuItem("GameObject/XXX/DoTest", false, 100)]
    private static void DoTest()
    {
        Debug.Log("DoTest");
    }
}
```

save, and check if there is a new menu item in the context menu and *it won't be there*. Now change the `priority` parameter to `10` or `1` and try again - it won't appear anyway. Sometimes even commenting/uncommenting and reloading the editor doesn't help.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: well, should it not be public instead of private?

Comment: In their example all functions are private https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MenuItem.html

Comment: The constructor example page has public method names. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MenuItem-ctor.html

Comment: Public methods don't work either when `itemName = "GameObject/..."` and `priority = 100` or greater.